# would have liked

Tags: modal-verbs

The company included more swords than Catelyn **would have liked**. Three by the fire wore the red stallion badge of the Brackens, and there was a large party in blue steel ringmail and capes of a silvery grey. On their shoulder was another familiar sigil, the twin towers of House Frey. She studied their faces, but they were all too young to have known her. The senior among them **would have been** no older than Bran when she went north.

1. I think the first "would have" is backshift of "would", meaning "wanted".
2. I think the second "would have" has an implied condition: if it had been the time when she went to the north, the senior among them would have been no older than Bran.

Is my thinking right?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not.

The first "would have" is a counterfactual conditional: If they had had fewer, she would have liked it

The second is an epistemic "would" - the meaning is something like "she guessed or concluded that she was".

**Edit:** corrected "more" to "fewer" according to comments.

Comment: Thank you very much, Colin. 1. So in what cases can "would have pp" be backshift, meaning "wanted"? 2. I didn't know "would have pp" can also be epistemic. Can you give me some examples of epistemic use of "would have pp"?

Comment: More or fewer in the first case?

Comment: Sorry, @MvLog: I did mean "fewer". Didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: "Would have" for "wanted" is archaic or very literary: you won't find it in normal speech or writing. For epistemic "would have": common in exchanges like "When did you go into town? Oh, it would have been Thursday or Friday".

Comment: @Colin Fine Thank you again! So by "epistemic", you mean "would have pp" can refer to "assumption/belief of past situations, based on some indirect evidence", right?

Comment: @Colin Fine And by "When did you go into town? Oh, it would have been Thursday or Friday", you mean the speaker didn't remember the time when he himself went into the town, so he had to guess when?

Comment: @StoneyB: yes. My Log pointed this out, and I acknowledged the error, an hour before you posted. But I didn't edit the reply - I have done so now.

Comment: @thetazuo: yes. Except that he's probably doing something with a bit more certainty than just guessing: probably he knows that it must have been either Thursday or Friday, but does not remember which.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Thank you again! But I am not sure what you mean by "epistemic". Do you mean "would have pp" can refer to "assumption/belief of past situations?

Comment: @thetazuo: most modals in English and other languages have two different meanings, one about causality and dependency in the external world (which may include social phenomena like oblgations), and one about somebody's knowledge or expectations concerning the external world. The former is called a _deontic_ meaning, and the latter an _epistemic_ one. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality).